# Automaton backedge arrows running into other states

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, automata

I am trying to draw a finite-state automaton using the `automata` package in Ti*k*Z and am having trouble getting an edge to "clear" the other states (that is, not run into them).  Having read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57927/10906), I used `bend` for the edge from `q1` to `q8`; while that edge "clears" `q5` and `q6`, when I tried the same for the backedge from `q7` to `q2`, it didn't work.  I also tried `in` and `out` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20992/10906) to no avail.

It seems any combination of `bend`, `in`, and `out` parameters that I try still causes that edge to run into `q3` and `q4`.  I know I'm missing something, but what?  The [documentation](http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf#page=175) on the `automata` package is a bit thin in this regard.

Here's my current MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,topaths}

\let\oldepsilon\epsilon
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',node distance=1.5cm,semithick,auto]
    \node                   (l)                             {$\cdots$};
    \node[state]            (q1)    [right of=l]            {$1$};
    \node[state]            (q2)    [right of=q1]           {$2$};
    \node[state]            (q3)    [above right of=q2]     {$3$};
    \node[state]            (q4)    [right of=q3]           {$4$};
    \node[state]            (q5)    [below right of=q2]     {$5$};
    \node[state]            (q6)    [right of=q5]           {$6$};
    \node[state]            (q7)    [below right of=q4]     {$7$};
    \node[state]            (q8)    [right of=q7]           {$8$};
    \node                   (r)     [right of=q8]           {$\cdots$};

    \path[->]   (l)     edge                        node        {}              (q1)
                (q1)    edge                        node        {$\epsilon$}    (q2)
                        edge [bend right=60]        node[swap]  {$\epsilon$}    (q8)
                (q2)    edge                        node        {$\epsilon$}    (q3)
                        edge                        node        {$\epsilon$}    (q5)
                (q3)    edge                        node        {a}             (q4)
                (q4)    edge                        node        {$\epsilon$}    (q7)
                (q5)    edge                        node        {b}             (q6)
                (q6)    edge                        node        {$\epsilon$}    (q7)
                (q7)    edge                        node        {$\epsilon$}    (q8)
                        edge [in=90,out=90,above]   node        {$\epsilon$}    (q2)
                (q8)    edge                        node        {}              (r);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Compiled]

Comment: Add `distance=2cm,` to the edge options.

Comment: Setting `looseness=1.5` edge options will also work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [percusse's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94663/automaton-backedge-arrows-running-into-other-states/94664#comment202517_94663), I found that adding the `distance` option to the edge did the trick, adjusting the `in` and `out` values to get it just right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,topaths}

\let\oldepsilon\epsilon
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',node distance=1.5cm,semithick,auto]
    \node                   (l)                             {$\cdots$};
    \node[state]            (q1)    [right of=l]            {$1$};
    \node[state]            (q2)    [right of=q1]           {$2$};
    \node[state]            (q3)    [above right of=q2]     {$3$};
    \node[state]            (q4)    [right of=q3]           {$4$};
    \node[state]            (q5)    [below right of=q2]     {$5$};
    \node[state]            (q6)    [right of=q5]           {$6$};
    \node[state]            (q7)    [below right of=q4]     {$7$};
    \node[state]            (q8)    [right of=q7]           {$8$};
    \node                   (r)     [right of=q8]           {$\cdots$};

    \path[->]   (l)     edge                                    node        {}              (q1)
                (q1)    edge                                    node        {$\epsilon$}    (q2)
                        edge [bend right=60]                    node[swap]  {$\epsilon$}    (q8)
                (q2)    edge                                    node        {$\epsilon$}    (q3)
                        edge                                    node        {$\epsilon$}    (q5)
                (q3)    edge                                    node        {a}             (q4)
                (q4)    edge                                    node        {$\epsilon$}    (q7)
                (q5)    edge                                    node        {b}             (q6)
                (q6)    edge                                    node        {$\epsilon$}    (q7)
                (q7)    edge                                    node        {$\epsilon$}    (q8)
                        edge [in=120,out=60,above,distance=2cm] node        {$\epsilon$}    (q2)
                (q8)    edge                                    node        {}              (r);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled Solution]

Comment: You can retain the `in=90,out=90` option. Looks better that way imho.

Comment: @hpesoj626 I guess we disagree on the aesthetics, then.  The new `in` and `out` values I've chosen work well for my purposes.